# Не получается определить тип Exeption при вызове Assert.Fail

Tags: c#, события, mstest

Есть код:

```
private void SaveException(object source, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Exception is AssertFailedException)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TestResult.TestException))
            {
                TestResult.TestException = e.Exception.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вызываю этот метод обычным Assert.Fail("message")
Но после строки `Assert.Fail("message");` при проверке в блоке if я получаю False, почему так происходит, мне не понятно, хотя тип в любом случае будет **AssertFailedException**.
Подскажите!

Однако, если я добавлю переменную в метод **SaveException** 
`var exType = e.Exeption.GetType()`
При проверке в If будет true, почему так происходит - не понятно.
[image: Debag]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если тип `AssertFailedException`, то `false` быть не может, проблема вероятно в другом.

Comment: А вы посмотрите в отладчике, что у вас всё-таки в `e.Exception`, или напечатайте в консоль. Может у вас там `AggregateException`, например, всяко бывает.

Comment: Да, `Debug.Fail(e.Exception)`

Comment: `При проверке в If будет true` - код проверки надо угадать? Не экономьте буквы, они бесплатные. Покажите измененный код, который работает.

Comment: Добавлю изображение, минуту

Comment: Да, добавьте ниже код как вы добавили переменную и каким кодом проверили, что получилось `true`

Comment: Выше два скрина в вопросе

Comment: Что, реально `== true` помогло? А если убрать?

Comment: Вызываю в другом методе с помощью Assert.Fail(""); , после этого с помощью ивента оказываюсь в методе выше и соответственно проверяю

Comment: мне кажется, он параллелит исключения и происходит вот это и обрезается CallStack

Comment: Не вижу связи между CallStack и типом исключения. Тип приложения и версия дотнета какие?

Comment: Vs 19, Net 4.5.2

Comment: == true избыточно), не из за него, и уж тем более не из за var exType, вообщем он как то рандомно выкидывает нужное исключение, но это очень странно

Comment: просто, наверное, я вас не понял, если про само приложение то это фрейм для  ui тестов на MsTest

Comment: @Илья Попытайтесь поймать "неправильное" исключение. Если удастся посмотреть его тип, возможно ситуация станет гораздо понятнее.

Comment: Я про тип приложения спрашивал, а не про версию студии. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Дело в том, что код уже зашел в блок if и соответственно записал значение в переменную,
 оказывается, что ***FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs*** выбрасывает нам сразу несколько исключений, я не поставил точку останова на строчке `TestResult.TestException = e.Exception.ToString();`